# How to save textinput value when we dismiss an overly?

Tags: react-native

I am using an overly in my screen. The overly has a textinput and a button in it, and the button has an onPress=saveInput() function in it. I want to perform same action but on overly dismiss. i.e. I want to call saveInput() method on dismissing the overly. Is there a way I can do so? Here is the snippet

```
<Overlay
    overlayStyle={...}
    isVisible={this.state.isprice} 
    onBackdropPress={...}>
    <ScrollView>
        <>
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    value={this.state.price}
                    keyboardType={"phone-pad"}
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ price: text })}
                    onFocus={() => {
                        this.setState({ price: '' })
                    }}
                />
                <View>
                    <Button
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.saveInput()
                        }}
                        title="Add"
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        </>
    </ScrollView>
</Overlay>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call saveinput inner onbackdropPress or where you update this.state.isprice

```
<Overlay
    overlayStyle={...}
    isVisible={this.state.isprice} 
    onBackdropPress={this.saveInput}>
    <ScrollView>
        <>
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    value={this.state.price}
                    keyboardType={"phone-pad"}
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ price: text })}
                    onFocus={() => {
                        this.setState({ price: '' })
                    }}
                />
                <View>
                    <Button
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.saveInput()
                        }}
                        title="Add"
                    />
                    <Button onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({isPrice: false});
                        this.saveInput()
                      }} title='Close Overlay'/>
                </View>
            </View>
        </>
    </ScrollView>
</Overlay>
```